# MongoDB atomic "findOrCreate": findOne, insert if nonexistent, but do not update

Tags: node.js, mongodb

as the title says, I want to perform a find (one) for a document, by _id, and if doesn't exist, have it created, then whether it was found or was created, have it returned in the callback.

I don't want to update it if it exists, as I've read findAndModify does. I have seen many other questions on Stackoverflow regarding this but again, don't wish to update anything.

I am unsure if by creating (of not existing), THAT is actually the update everyone is talking about, it's all so confuzzling :(

Answer (score 212, accepted):

Beginning with MongoDB 2.4, it's no longer necessary to rely on a unique index (or any other workaround) for atomic `findOrCreate` like operations.

This is thanks to [the `$setOnInsert` operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/setOnInsert/#op._S_setOnInsert) new to 2.4, which allows you to specify updates which should only happen when inserting documents.

This, combined with the `upsert` option, means you can use `findAndModify` to achieve an atomic `findOrCreate`-like operation.

```
db.collection.findAndModify({
  query: { _id: "some potentially existing id" },
  update: {
    $setOnInsert: { foo: "bar" }
  },
  new: true,   // return new doc if one is upserted
  upsert: true // insert the document if it does not exist
})
```

As `$setOnInsert` only affects documents being inserted, if an existing document is found, no modification will occur.  If no document exists, it will upsert one with the specified _id, then perform the insert only set.  In both cases, the document is returned.

Comment: Your code is used in mongodb shell, but how to use it in node.js code?

Comment: @Gank if you're using the mongodb native driver for node the syntax would be more like `collection.findAndModify({_id:'theId'}, <your sort opts>, {$setOnInsert:{foo: 'bar'}}, {new:true, upsert:true}, callback)`.  See [the docs](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html)

Comment: Is there a way to know if the document has been updated or inserted ?

Comment: @numbers1311407 This works great when POSTing new documents. But what about when PUTing already existing ones? Do you have any good soultions to my problem here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26055958/mongodb-unique-constraints-on-a-date-range

Comment: If I understand what you're saying, the answer is just to remove the `$setOnInsert`.  The purpose of this modifier is to *not* update existing records.  If you want to affect existing records, the normal `update` will do that.

Comment: @numbers1311407 Take your example above: You query for a _id, if not found, create a new document with the combination of `upsert` and `$setOnInsert`. But what if i later want to **change** the `_id` of this particular document, and **still avoid collision** with other potentially existing `_id`'s. A normal update will not ensure that no collission is made, and if this operation is split into a find (for looking after _id's) followed by update, we lose the atomicity. *(I know that most of the time there is no reason for change the _id, but for the sake of the problem, just pretend there is)*

Comment: @AndersÖstman `_id` is immutable and cannot be updated, atomically or no.  To answer your question for a field which *can* be changed, you could use `$set` which would always be applied and takes precedence over the query (`query: {foo: 1}, update: {$setOnInsert: {...}, $set: {foo: 2}}`).

Comment: Oh, the _id actually IS immutable. =) I never felt the need to change it and therefore actually did not know that this could not be done.

Comment: can we use "findAndModify" in the Bulk Operations?

Comment: @techie_28 No, `findAndModify` works on a single doc and doesn't accept a `multi` param like update does.

Comment: I want to check if an email address exists in a collection and insert if it doesnt. I got this

bulk.find({email:"xyc@yahoo.com"}).upsert().update({$setOnInsert:{status:"I",points:"0"} })

If that is correct can we make bulk query operations dynamically?

Comment: I didn't understand what you were talking about at first.  I'm not very familiar with the bulk API.  From looking at the docs it appears that it should work as written (though maybe you'd use `updateOne`).  I also cannot say whether or not it would be atomic.  It's a bit outside the scope of this question I think.

Comment: If you want **to check if** the query above(`db.collection.findAndModify({query: {_id: "some potentially existing id"}, update: {$setOnInsert: {foo: "bar"}}, new: true, upsert: true})`) **insert(upsert)ed** a document, you should consider using `db.collection.updateOne({_id: "some potentially existing id"}, {$setOnInsert: {foo: "bar"}}, {upsert: true})`. It returns `{"acknowledged": true, "matchedCount": 0, "modifiedCount": 0, "upsertedId": ObjectId("for newly inserted one")}` if the doc inserted, `{"acknowledged": true, "matchedCount": 1, "modifiedCount": 0}` if the doc already exists.

Comment: seems to be deprecated in flavor of `findOneAndUpdate`, `findOneAndReplace` or `findOneAndDelete`

Comment: One needs to be careful here, though. This only works if the selector of the findAndModify/findOneAndUpdate/updateOne uniquely identifies one document by _id. Otherwise the upsert is split up on the server into a query and an update/insert. The update will still be atomic. But the query and the update together will not be executed atomically.

Comment: Since, in the solution, update is not carried out. How can we do this: If document exists then update, but if it does not exist then create and set one more field.

Answer (score 29):

## Driver Versions > 2

**Using the latest driver (> version 2)**, you'll use [findOneAndUpdate](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.0/api/Collection.html#findOneAndUpdate) as `findAndModify` was deprecated. The new method takes 3 arguments, the `filter`, the `update` object (which contains your default properties, that should be inserted for a new object), and `options` where you have to specify the upsert operation.

Using the promise syntax, it looks like this:

```
const result = await collection.findOneAndUpdate(
  { _id: new ObjectId(id) },
  {
    $setOnInsert: { foo: "bar" },
  },
  {
    returnOriginal: false,
    upsert: true,
  }
);

const newOrUpdatedDocument = result.value;
```

Answer (score 6):

Its a bit dirty, but you can just insert it.

Be sure that the key has a unique index on it (if you use the _id it's ok, it's already unique).

In this way if the element is already present it will return an exception that you can catch.

If it isn't present, the new document will be inserted.

**Updated:** a detailed explanation of this technique on the [MongoDB Documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/isolate-sequence-of-operations/)

Comment: ok, thats a good idea, but for the pre-existing value it will return an error but NOT the value itself, right?

Comment: This is actually one of the recommended  solutions for isolated sequences  of operations (find then create if not found, presumably) http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/isolate-sequence-of-operations/

Comment: @Discipol if you want to do a set of atomic operations, you should first lock the Document, then modify it, and at the end release it.  This will require more queries, but you can optimize for the best case scenario and do only 1-2 queries most of the times.
see: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/perform-two-phase-commits/

Answer (score -2):

Here's what I did (Ruby MongoDB driver):

`$db[:tags].update_one({:tag => 'flat'}, {'$set' => {:tag => 'earth' }}, { :upsert => true })}`

It will update it if it exists, and insert it if it doesn't.