# MongoDB Atomic "Insert If Absent"

Tags: mongodb

I came across this -

[MongoDB atomic "findOrCreate": findOne, insert if nonexistent, but do not update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16358857/mongodb-atomic-findorcreate-findone-insert-if-nonexistent-but-do-not-update)

What I want is -

- If document is Absent, I insert one and return SUCCESS
- If document is Present, return FAILURE

Can I achieve this?

Comment: If you insert on a unique key such as _id then it will have this behaviour by default

Comment: Yea..I am doing something similar.. I am doing insert on a unique field to achieve this..

Comment: as @Sammaye stated above, [`insert()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insert/#db.collection.insert) does *exactly* that. Have you had any problems with `insert()`?

Comment: Sammaye solved my problem.. I am using what he suggested but I had figured the same out myself as well..