# How to get count of upserted documents with $setOnInsert?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I use the following update query in mongoose:

```
Doc.findOneAndUpdate({
  name: 'Ekik'
}, {$setOnInsert: {key: value}}, {upsert: true, new: true}, function (err, doc) {
     // How to get upserted count here?
     console.log(doc.isNew); // always true either document upserted or don't
});
```

I need to get count of inserted documents. How could I do it?

Comment: You do realize you are passing in the ObjectId value as the query? Either you just generated this so **one inserted** or you got that from somewhere and expect it to exist so **one updated**.

Comment: I need to hack like the following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16358857/mongodb-atomic-findorcreate-findone-insert-if-nonexistent-but-do-not-update but I just need to know either document was inserted

Comment: Read the comment again, it's pretty clear. You are finding by _id. So does it exist in the collection or not. the "One" in the name of the method should give you a hint to how many.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't understand how could I get upserted document. Either I use {new: true} I always get some document but I can't know either it upserted or existed

Comment: new: `true` is the default being the modified document. Try new: `false`

Comment: If I set {new: false} I don't get upserted document. I need to get only upserted document in the callback above or null if there is no upserted one

Answer (score 0):

The return signature of [`findOneAndUpdate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate) in the callback is the `err` and the `document` that was either modified or inserted. There is also a default case that the document returned is the "modified" document unless you set the argument to `false`.

Looking an an example case:

```
    var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
        Schema = mongoose.Schema,
        ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;

    mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');

    var uptestSchema = new Schema({
      value: Number
    });

    var Uptest = mongoose.model( "uptest", uptestSchema, "uptest" );

    var id = new ObjectId("538c1fea6369faeced1b7bfb");

    console.log( id )

    Uptest.findOneAndUpdate(
      { _id: id },
      { "$setOnInsert": { value: 3 } },
      { upsert: true, new: false },
      function(err, doc) {

        console.log( doc );

      }
    );
```

Now if the document for the given `_id` existed then I would expect to see the "original" document without modifications returned. There is only **`$setOnInsert`** in there anyway so there would be no change.

If however an "upsert" occurred the return value for the "original" document would be `null` since there was no document originally. This is what tells you the operation resulted in an "upsert" and created a new document.

Comment: Thanks for the response but why we can't know either document upserted by using isNew value. (I've updated the post)

Comment: @Erik As I told you when `new: false` then an a new document results in the the `doc` value in the callback being `null`. Otherwise it is the original document. `null` means a new document was inserted.

Comment: Yes I understand but I need to get inserted document in callback method. How could I get it

Comment: @Erik Well your only arguments are the `_id` and `$setOnInsert` so those are the only values that are in the document. Alternately leave the default `new: true` and if the `$setOnInsert` value is not reflected in the returned document then it was not inserted but only updated. It's just a case of logic to which method you choose.

Comment: Actually I have no Object for query and update document (it's just example) So are any possibilities to know what I need?

Comment: @Erik I really don't understand how I can make this any clearer than what I have already said. There are several ways presented of how to tell whether the document is inserted as a new document or not, it is a basic comparison to the arguments you supply which are either present or not.