# MongoDb unique constraints on a Date range

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoskin

Im using MongoDb with Mongoskin. In a collection I'm saving events. 
Among other fields, these events have a start and an end, saved as `Dates` in Mongodb.

```
events { 
  start: "Date1",
  end: "Date2",
  ...
}
```

When inserting new documents in this collection I need a constrain that forbids insertion of document which start-end dates overlapping an event alreay created. In short, I dont want any events share the same time span.

**Question:** Is there a way to handle this constraint trough MongoDb with some kind of unique index? I think not, but please correct me if I'm wrong!

If not:

**Question** Do I have to check possible overlaps trough code before inserting new events? Do I need to set up some kind of write lock, so that another user can't squeeze in an event between the time I check for overlaps and inserting my own event? How is this done in MongoDb?

**EDIT**

This is the best way i have come up with so far, it actually seems to work pretty good.

```
var input = getPostInput();

var query = {$and: [
  {start: {$lte: input.end}},
  {end: {$gte: input.start}}
]};
db.events.findAndModify(query, {}, {$setOnInsert: input}, {new: true, upsert: true}, callback)
```

It uses the `findAndModify` as a type of "findOrCreate" operator. `$setOnInsert` add the POST input properties only if the `findAndModify` don't find a document, and `upsert: true` says it should create an document if none is found. These two options in combination seems to create a findOrCreate operator.

**EDIT**

Problems arise when updating (PUT) an event. I can't reuse the code above because it's relies on `upsert` and `$setOnInsert`.

**EDIT**

@wdberkeley:

I'm still struggling with this main problem: **ensure uniqueness on a range**. The more I think about it, it seems that "the array of time slices" might be the most non problematic solution. For example, lets say that 5 minutes is chosen as the smallest time period, and the average booking is 45 minutes. This would require me to save 9 numbers (probably `date`s): `timespan = [0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40]`, instead of two: `start=0, end=45`.
This is more than **four times** more saved data for the average booking. 
I dont mean to be harsh, but don't you see this as a problem? Or does it become a problem first when the saved data is **10 times** larger or **100 times** larger? I do realise that this is also relative to the totalt amount of bookings actually made...

Comment: I've been researching this problem and I think this is the best solution.  As long as you keep the number of values in your indexes field down to a reasonable size (e.g. Not thousands per document), this should work well.  I'm guessing that internally mongo is quite efficient about how it indexes the array of integers uniquely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a dead simple way to do this in MongoDB. I cooked up one alternative option that could work for you. If your dates come in discrete steps, like if this is for a booking application where users reserve objects by the day or the hour, then you can use a combination of unique indexes and multikey indexes. For example, suppose reservations are by day. John Q reserves October 11 to October 14, inclusive. That is something like the 281st to 284th days of the year - let's assume that's exactly which days it is. Save the reservation field as an array of the days that are reserved

```
> db.reservations.insert({ "span" : [ 281, 282, 283, 284 ] })
```

Put a unique index on the `span` field.

```
> db.reservations.ensureIndex({ "span" : 1}, { "unique" : 1 })
```

Now you can't insert a document that has any of those days in its span:

```
> db.reservations.insert({ "span" : [ 279, 280, 281, 282 ] })
// unique key error
```

This might work for you with some additional tweaking to take into account the year, or it might be part of a compound unique index to make the timespans unique by e.g. `room_id` for hotel booking.

Another way is just to coordinate the checks on the client side. If you have multiple clients that don't talk to each other at all I guess the best way to do this would be to share a "lock" in the database: `findAndModify` a document in a `lock` collection to check and acquire a lock. Once a client has the lock by changing a field on that document, it can do the check for overlaps with a query and then the insert if all is well, then release the lock by changing the flag on the lock document again.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Please read my edit on the question above and see if my solution was something you meant in your last paragraph. About the "lock", I dont know what that means exacly, but as I have understood this `findAndModify` will be done atomicaly, and therefore "lock" the collection so that other users cannot squeese in events between the query and the update phase of the `findAndModify` operation. Correct?

Comment: Lets say I put a lock on the whole collection, and a second user is trying to save a event when the first user are owning the lock. How shoud i respont to the second users atempt? With a error message?

Comment: What's the problem with your solution if you're putting an already create event? I thought you didn't want to allow overlaps? You can also just have a separate update route. You would probably have a retry loop for the lock for the second user, but I think your simpler solution should work so it doesn't really matter.

Comment: I don't want to allow overlaps =). My solution works when creating new events, but not when updating the time on events already created. My way of using the findAndModify will not work in an update, because the way I use the findAndModify relies on creating NEW document only. It seems that I need some kind of lock here, or do you see some update solution that I don't? Keep in mind that when updating i also need to check to that times does not overlap.

Comment: If you're updating a doc that already exists, update it using the `_id` reference. The exact details of how to go about this depend on how your updates happen on the application side.

Comment: Thanks for all your help, I have added a last edit on my question above. I would appreciate if you could share your thoughts regarding my added speculations...