# How to create a document if it doesn't exist MongoDB Javascript?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

How do I create a document if it doesn't exist with MongoDB?

```
if(db.collection.find({_id: _id}) == null) {
  db.collection.insertOne({_id: _id});
}
```

Thats the logic of what i'm thinking.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [insert if nonexistent, but do not update](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16358857/mongodb-atomic-findorcreate-findone-insert-if-nonexistent-but-do-not-update)

Comment: @adeneo I have tried that but I get the error `MongoError: need remove or update`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please try this one

```
> var _id = 'the-black-horse-london-pub-san-francisco';
> if (db.users.find({_id: _id}).count() == 0) {db.users.insert({_id: _id})}
> db.users.find({})
  { "_id" : "the-black-horse-london-pub-san-francisco" }
```

Comment: The if statement I put in my question was just pseudo code and doesn't work, and I'm not trying to make a new `ObjectId()`; I'm just trying to find an _id or any parameter.

Comment: Its just a string an example is `the-black-horse-london-pub-san-francisco`

Comment: @NathanO, I have updated my answer, the correct way could be done through check the `cousor.count()`. since the `find` return cursors...

Answer (score 8):

You can do this atomically with an empty upsert:

```
db.collection.update({_id: _id}, {}, {upsert: true});
```

If a document with a matching `_id` already exists the update will be a no-op, otherwise a document will be created.

Comment: this should be the correct answer as .insert is deprecated.