# atomic method in mongoDB using node: find object, create if nonexistant

Tags: node.js, mongodb, find

im having issues finding an atomic method for finding a single object in MongoDB and creating it with some preset values if it doesn't exist yet. 
I found a thread ([MongoDB atomic "findOrCreate": findOne, insert if nonexistent, but do not update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16358857/mongodb-atomic-findorcreate-findone-insert-if-nonexistent-but-do-not-update)) but the method findAndModify is deprecated and it seems to me that findOneAndUpdate always updates the object, therefore resetting all my data when an object is found, rather than just returning the found one without changing it.

Thanks in advance, i've searched a lot but didn't find anything that helped me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the `upsert` option, normally it create the document if it canno't find it

Comment: yes thats what i need, but as far as i see correctly it always upserts/modifies the object, even if it exists. That's not what i want though, i just want to find it without changing anything while making sure it exists

Comment: The `upsert` option is defined to create a new document if the filter don't match any documents. So if it already exist, it will update your document, not create a new one, except if your filter is bad

Comment: yeah thats exactly why the method doesn't work for me and im looking for one that works. i **dont** want it to change anything if it exists

Comment: So I don't understand the problem. You want to find a document and create it if it doesn't already exist right ?

Comment: oh okay i now see that $setoninsert should take care that it doesn't chnage the object if it doesnt create it using findeOneAndUpdate, so using `let result = await db.collection("users").findOneAndUpdate({_id:userid}, {$setOnInsert:{ warnings: 0, bans: 0, kicks: 0, botusage: 0, sound: false }}, {returnNewDocument:true, upsert:true}); ` should do the trick?

Comment: yeah i just needed to work around the weirdness that their node.js methods use differently named tags in the options than in their documentation and then it worked thanks for sticking with me